# Ссылка на реализацию без экземпляра

Tags: c++, ооп

Начал изучать книгу Эрика и Элизабет Фримен Паттерны проектирования. Пытаюсь написать на C++ архитектуру из первой главы.

[image: Архитектура]

Как в конструкторе наследника Duck (RedheadDuck) присвоить указателю FlyBehaviour FlyWithWings? В FlyWithWings одна статическая функция, и не хотелось бы создавать где-то в main()-е экземпляр, а потом передавать его в конструктор, можно ли как-то этого избежать?

Код:

```
class FlyBehaviour {
public:
  static virtual void fly() = 0;
};

class FlyWithWings : public FlyBehaviour {
public:
  static void fly() {
    cout << "I'm flying with wings!" << endl;
  }
};

class Duck {
private:
  FlyBehaviour *flyBehaviour;
public:
  virtual void display() = 0;
  void fly() {flyBehaviour->fly();}
};

class RedheadDuck : public Duck {
  RedheadDuck() {
    // Как присвоить flyBehaviour указатель на FlyWithWings?
  }
  void display() {
    cout << "I'm redhead duck." << endl;
  }
};
```

Всем спасибо, сделал так:

```
class FlyBehaviour {
public:
  virtual void fly() = 0;
};

class FlyWithWings : public FlyBehaviour {
public:
  void fly() {
    cout << "I'm flying with wings!" << endl;
  }
};

class Duck {
protected:
  FlyBehaviour *flyBehaviour;
public:
  Duck() {flyBehaviour = nullptr;}
  virtual void display() = 0;
  void fly() {flyBehaviour->fly();}
  ~Duck() {delete flyBehaviour;}
};

class RedheadDuck : public Duck {
public:
  RedheadDuck() {
    Duck::flyBehaviour = new FlyWithWings;
  }
  void display() {
    cout << "I'm redhead duck." << endl;
  }
};
```

Comment: хранить ссылки в членах класса? Используйте указатели - ссылки сдесь совсем не вариант

Comment: что касается как присвить УКАЗАТЕЛЬ(!!!!) класса-наследника указателю класса-родителя, то сдесь вообще нет проблем - просто берете и присваиваете. Если не хотите в main создавать экземпляр класса для инициализации, то просто установите аргумент по умолчанию, если, конечно, такое допстимо. Иначе придется явно указывать при инициализации каким классом вы хотите инициализировать

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, ссылки в членах класса это абсолютно нормальное явление.

Comment: @ixSci 1) как в этом случае разместить в членах класса ссылку на абстрактный класс, которая бы указывала на наследника? 2) что будет со ссылкой, когда объект уничтожится при выходе из конструктора?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, 1) `Abstract& abstract = derived;` не важно в членах класса это или нет. 2) не понимаю, что это значит. Почему что-то должно уничтожиться?

Comment: @ixSci в этом случае нет (в этом случае мне непонятно даже зачем так делать?), но если нам нужно проинициализировать при создании объекта? Когда в конструктор передаем объект или ссылку на него? (в первом случае временный объеукт будет уничтожен при выходе из конструктора, а во втором время жизни объекта может быть разным)

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, ссылка это удобное средство передачи зависимости в класс. Это в сущности невладеющий, ненулевой указатель — очень удобная штука при внедрении зависимостей. Про уничтожение я так ничего и не понял. Временем жизни зависимости владеет тот, кто передаёт зависимость. Временный объект в lvalue-ссылку передать не удастся.

Comment: @ixSci да при чем тут временный объект? у вас, допустим, есть конструктор, который получает ссылку на объект, которую нужно присвоить ссылке в вашем классе - это понятно? Раз мы передаем ссылку, логично предположить, что сам объект у нас на стэке. Так вот, раз мы передаем ссылку то что станет с ссылкой в нашем классе, когда объект будет уничтожен? Или даже, если объект был создан в куче, то что будет с этой же ссылкой, когда мы решим избавиться от объекта? Мы получим ссылку, которая указывает на уже уничтоженный объект. Для указателя же эта проблема решена через интелектуальные указатели.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, объект не обязательно на стеке. Про время жизни я уже написал: это забота того, кто владеет зависимостью. Ситуации, при которой зависимость будет уничтожена раньше наступить не может, об этом заботиться тот, кто управляет зависимостями.

Comment: @ixSci окей, можете это продемонстировать на данном примере?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, в комментариях? Нет конечно. Как Вы это себе представляете? А в качестве ответа это всё оффтопик.

Comment: @ixSci я не говорил про комментарии. Ну а что касается ответа - почему нет? Будет очень полезно не только вопрошающему, но и другим, например мне. Мне, например, самому интересно, как это сделать через ссылки и ничего при этом не сломать.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch про ссылки вы наверное [такую](https://ideone.com/n9jSBK) ситуацию имели в виду ? У меня на машине такой пример падает (ну я ничего другого и не ожидал).

Comment: @vegorov да, совершенно верно, об этом я и говорил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то так:

```
class RedheadDuck : public Duck {
  RedheadDuck(FlyBehaviour *in) : Duck{in} {
  }
  void display() {
    cout << "I'm redhead duck." << endl;
  }
};
```

Как видите, сдесь не хватает соответствующего конструктора для Duck

```
class Duck {
private:
  FlyBehaviour *flyBehaviour;
public:
  Duck(FlyBehaviour *in) : flyBehaviour{in}{};
  virtual void display() = 0;
  void fly() {flyBehaviour->fly();}
};
```

Если же вы не хотите каждый раз явно указывать при инициализации чем его нужно инициализировать, то установите аргумент по умолчанию:

```
RedheadDuck(FlyBehaviour *in = new FlyWithWings) : Duck{in}
```

Так, если вы не передадите при инициализации аргументы, будет использован аргумент по умолчанию, но если вам нужен другой аргумент, то придется использовать его при явной инициализации.

Главное, раз уж работаете с указателями, предусмотрите освобождение памяти в деструкторе, либо используйте интеллектуальные указатели

Comment: Можете пояснить за что минус?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы присвоить указатель на экземпляр `FlyWithWings` этот экземпляр сначала надо создать, а это сделать невозможно, так как это абстрактный класс, так как он не реализует метод `fly`. Встроенная система полиморфизма не допускает статических виртуальных методов. Так что `static virtual void fly() = 0;` является ошибкой синтаксиса. Делайте метод не статическим, реализуйте его в `FlyWithWings`, создавайте экземпляр `FlyWithWings` и присваивайте указателю адрес этого экземпляра. Если же никакого состояния хранить не требуется, то можно вместо указателя на класс использовать указатель на метод.